# ForEach method with an error `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time;`

Tags: swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

I'm having an error `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

There are some articles about the same error and I tried to solve this, but I can't do it in my case...

would someone mind advising me on how to solve this?

---

Here is the code:

**EDITED**

```
import SwiftUI

struct InfoView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {

    Button(action: {
                appState.makeGetCallInfo()
            }) {
                Text("Hit API")
            }

        ForEach(appState.arrayInfos ?? []){ info in

            VStack{
                Group{
                  Text(String(info.id))
                  Text(String(info.no_1))
                  Text(String(info.no_2))
                  Text(info.name_1)
                  Text(info.name_2 ?? "")
                  Text(info.name_3)
                  Text(info.name_4 ?? "")
                  Text(String(info.no_3 ?? 0))
                  Text(info.name_5 ?? "")
                  Text(String(info.no_4 ?? 0))
                }
                Group{
                  Text(String(info.no_5 ?? 0))
                  Text(info.name_6 ?? "")
                  Text(String(info.no_7))
                  Text(String(info.no_8))
                  Text(info.name_7 ?? "")
                  Text(info.name_8)
                  Text(info.memo ?? "")
                  Text(info.created_at)
                  Text(info.updated_at)
                  Text(String(info.userId))
                }
                  Divider()
                      .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I reduce the number of subviews in VStack like below, it works well. the error disappears

```
import SwiftUI
    
struct InfoView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(appState.arrayInfos ?? []){ info in

            VStack{
                Group{
                  Text(String(info.id))
                  Text(String(info.no_1))
                  Text(String(info.no_2))
                  Text(info.name_1)
                  Text(info.name_2 ?? "")
                  Text(info.name_3)
                  Text(info.name_4 ?? "")
                  Text(String(info.no_3 ?? 0))
                  Text(info.name_5 ?? "")
                  Text(String(info.no_4 ?? 0))
                }
                  Divider()
                      .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AppState.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine


class AppState: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var arrayInfos:[Infos]?

    func makeGetCallInfo() {
        // Set up the URL request
        let endpoint: String = "https://sample.com/api/info/?user=1"
        
        guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.addValue("token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
        
        // make the request
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) in
            // check for any errors
            guard error == nil else {
                print("error calling GET")
                print(error!)
                return
            }
            // make sure we got data
            guard let responseData = data else {
                print("Error: did not receive data")
                return
            }
            // parse the result as JSON, since that's what the API provides
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                do{ self.arrayInfos = try JSONDecoder().decode([Infos].self, from: responseData)
                }catch{
                    print("Error: did not decode")
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

JsonModel.swift

```
import Foundation

struct Infos: Codable,Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var no_1: Int
    var no_2: Int
    var name_1: String
    var name_2: String?
    var name_3: String
    var name_4: String?
    var no_3: Int?
    var name_5: String?
    var no_4: Int?

    var no_5: Int?
    var name_6: String?
    var no_7: Int
    var no_8: Int
    var name_7: String?
    var name_8: String
    var memo: String?
    var created_at: String
    var updated_at: String
    var userId: Int
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Your VStack contains too many subviews, it is allowed maximum 10. So group them by less amount, like below

```
VStack{
  Group {
    Text(String(info.id))
    Text(String(info.no_1))
    Text(String(info.no_2))
    Text(info.name_1)
    Text(info.name_2 ?? "")
    Text(info.name_3)
    Text(info.name_4 ?? "")
    Text(String(info.no_3 ?? 0))
    Text(info.name_5 ?? "")
    Text(String(info.no_4 ?? 0))
  }
  Group {
    Text(String(info.no_5 ?? 0))
    Text(info.name_6 ?? "")
    Text(String(info.no_7))
    Text(String(info.no_8))
    Text(info.name_7 ?? "")
    Text(info.name_8)
    Text(info.memo ?? "")
    Text(info.created_at)
    Text(info.updated_at)
    Text(String(info.userId))
  }
    Divider()
        .padding()
}
```

*Note: it is preferable to separate such big containers into dedicated view and just create it here.*

Comment: I tried editing  with`Group{}` but I still have the same error.

Comment: Would you show what is AppState and dependent types?

Answer (score 1):

Break it down into smaller views. For example, make every Group a separate sub View.

Pass the info object from your loop into the subview